# Unable to install iptables [HELP]

Tags: linux, iptables

Hello so I removed iptables for reasons I don't even know but when reinstalling i get this error

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package iptables is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'iptables' has no installation candidate

Comment: bump any help??

Comment: Which Linux distro you are using? And can you please share the screen-shot of the error which you get while installing iptables